# PHP Object not rendering new data on WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a PHP function that fetches the details of a single "lp_course" post by name and stores it in an associative array named "$course_detail".

It is working, but when i select new course using form, page reloads and new array is created with single new course.

```
 $course_details = array();

if (isset($selected_value)) {
    $args = array(
        'name' => $selected_value,
        'post_type' => 'lp_course',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $course_post = $query->posts[0];

        // Get all the course details
        $course_title = get_the_title($course_post);
        $course_content = get_the_content(null, false, $course_post);
        $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words($course_content, 100, '...');

        $course_price = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_price', true);
        $course_duration = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_duration', true);
        $course_instructor = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_course_instructor', true);
        $course_level = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_course_level', true);
        $course_students = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_students', true);
        $course_categories = wp_get_post_terms($course_post->ID, 'course_category', array('fields' => 'names'));
        $course_category = $course_categories[0];
        $course_author_id = $course_post->post_author;
        $course_author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $course_author_id);
        $course_level = get_post_meta($course_post->ID, '_lp_level', true);

        // Create an associative array to store the course details
        $course_detail = array(
            'title' => $course_title,
            'content' => $trimmed_content,
            'price' => $course_price,
            'duration' => $course_duration,
            'instructor' => $course_instructor,
            'level' => $course_level,
            'students' => $course_students,
            'category' => $course_category,
            'author_name' => $course_author_name
        );

        // Append the course detail array to the course details array object
        array_push($course_details, $course_detail);
    }

    // Restore the global post object
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I want to store selected courses data in array, similar to adding product in cart. so that i can loop through and display data on frontend.

Comment: Same as a "cart" stores the selected products somewhere, you will have to store your selected courses somewhere then. Stick them into a session (custom session with WP always has a bit of issues), or make your selection form pass them along via a hidden input field or something.